# IFileStore unable to read from path with accented characters Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

[IFileStore](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Ffilesystem%2FIFileStore.html) represents a file in the local file system of my RCP app. This works perfectly in windows for any path. However, in mac os , iFileStore object unable to fetch information correctly if path contains accented characters like *á é í.*

```
IFileInfo iFileInfo = iFileStore.fetchInfo();
```

Anyway this can be handled ?

Answer (score 0):

macOS uses 'decomposed' format for file paths - the accent is stored separately from the character. This is known as Unicode NFD format.

In an Eclipse plug-in you can use `com.ibm.icu.text.Normalizer2` to convert a string to decomposed format

```
Normalizer2 normalizer = Normalizer2.getNFDInstance();

String decomposed = normalizer.normalize(string);
```

Use

```
EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore(new Path(decomposed));
```

to get the `IFileStore` from a path

Comment: Thanks @greg-449. Is there a way i can get a _IFileStore_ instance from path.  I am trying to  open file outside of workspace in my editor using _openEditorOnFileStore(IWorkbenchPage page, IFileStore fileStore)_ of [IDE class](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fui%2Fide%2FIDE.html). Currently _fileStore.fetchInfo()_ gives null when path contains accented chars.

Comment: Use `EFS` - see updated answer. Note that most APIs should already be giving decomposed paths on macOS so this may not be your problem.

Comment: I am using exactly this  @greg-449. However _openEditorOnFileStore(IWorkbenchPage page, IFileStore fileStore)_ gives java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.unix.UnixFileNatives.fetchFileInfo(UnixFileNatives.java:114)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.unix.UnixFileHandler.fetchFileInfo(UnixFileHandler.java:28)

Comment: That sounds like Eclipse bug [478064](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=478064) which appears to be about permissions on the file/directory

Comment: Yes. Exactly the same error stacktrace in my case. However, i am not 100%  sure if it is permission related. Methods like _iFileStore.fetchInfo().exists()_ fails when i have accented characters in path while _java.nio.file.Files.exists(Path)_ does not.

Comment: A quick test shows this works fine for me with both NFC and NFD composition. Eclipse 2018-12, Java 11.0.2, macOS 10.14.3

Comment: Thanks for confirmation @greg-449 . I checked with Eclipse 2018-12 and it worked. The issue is with mars version.